# Particle System "Rotation" Not listed

Tags: particles

New to Blender
v2.93.6

I don't see "Rotation" under ParticleSystem.

The video I'm following (using an older version) shows ParticleSystem
options as ..[] Hair Dynamics, Velocity, Rotation, Physics..

I have ..[] Hair Dynamics, Render, Viewport..  Rotation isn't an option.

The only mention of Rotation in my version of ParticleSystem is under Render/Object/[]"Object Rotation" but it doesn't rotate the particles and it doesn't have any settings for rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the *Advanced* option in the particle settings. I've checked with 2.93.5, 2.83.5 and 2.79b - the *Rotation* settings which are shown by default when you've set the particle system to *Emitter* are only available under *Hair* when you enable *Advanced*.

[image]